# I am trying to display Base64 video, ( AngularJS, NeDB)

Tags: angularjs, nedb

Anyone know about how to display Base64 video in angular js.

I am trying to display the image in HTML i get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAOvO.png

In database storing like https://i.stack.imgur.com/V807z.pn

My angular js controller https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuMhS.png

Html file https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJvy4.png